# Firebase email verification on sign up - best practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Im working on a web application with `React` and `firebase 9.9.4`
My goal is to have a sign up form that asks for the user's email address as well as password.
When the user signs up he gets an email to verify his email address. He clicks on the confirmation link which leads him to a confirmation page. After clicking the link, the user is stored as a user in the firebase database with his password. After this process, he is now able to log in with his email and password.

I used the firebase methods `sendSignInLinkToEmail`, `isSignInWithEmailLink` and `signInWithEmailLink` as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth?authuser=0&hl=de

But I don't know how to provide the password and how to check if everything worked well.

Here is my `signup.js` component

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SignUp(){
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const { signuplink } = useAuth()

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    
        try {
            setError("")
            await signuplink(email, password)
        } catch {
            console.log("Failed to sign in")
            setError("Failed to sign in")
        }
      }
    
    const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    }

    const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
        setPassword(e.target.value);
    }


    return (
        <form onSubmit={(e) => { handleSubmit(e) }}>
          {error}
          <h3> Sign-up Form </h3>
          <label>
            Email:
          </label><br />
          <input type="email" value={email} required onChange={(e) => { handleEmailChange(e) }} /><br />
          <label>
            Password:
          </label><br />
          <input type="password" value={password} required onChange={(e) => { handlePasswordChange(e) }} /><br />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          <div>
              Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Log In</Link>
          </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Here is my `signuplink` method to send a verification link

```
function signuplink(email, password) {
        const auth = getAuth();

        const actionCodeSettings = {
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/register-complete',
            handleCodeInApp: true
        };
          
        sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, actionCodeSettings)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("mail send")
            window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email);
            window.localStorage.setItem('passwordForSignIn', password);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorCode)
            console.log(errorMessage)
        });
    }
```

Here is my `RegisterComplete.js` component that shows up after the user clicked on the verification link:

```
import React from "react";
import { getAuth, isSignInWithEmailLink, signInWithEmailLink } from "firebase/auth";

export default function RegisterComplete(){
    const auth = getAuth();
    if (isSignInWithEmailLink(auth, window.location.href)) {
        let email = window.localStorage.getItem('emailForSignIn');
        let password = window.localStorage.getItem('passwordForSignIn');
        if (!email) {
            email = window.prompt('Please provide your email for confirmation');
        }
        signInWithEmailLink(auth, email, window.location.href)
            .then((result) => {
            window.localStorage.removeItem('emailForSignIn');
            console.log("signInWithEmailLink")
            })
            .catch((error) => {
            });
    }

    return (
        <>foo</>
    )
}
```

The only way I couldn't think of to save email and password information before the user's email is verified is to store both in `localStorage`. But if the user opens the link on another device then this information is not present. I think at some point I should call a `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to store the password? But I don't know where?

This spund like a pretty common process, so is there any best practice how to do it?

Thanks!